# Installing Gearman with PHP Extension on Debian 6.0.5 leads to error

Tags: php5, installation, php, gearman

What I have tried ...

```
# apt-get install php5-dev
# apt-get install gearman-job-server libgearman-dev
# pecl install gearman
```

Result ...

```
...
configure: error: Please install libgearman
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/gearman/configure' failed
```

Than I tried ...

```
# export GEARMAN_LIB_DIR=/usr/include/libgearman
# export GEARMAN_INC_DIR=/usr/include/libgearman
# pecl install gearman
```

Result ...

```
...
configure: error: libgearman version 0.21 or later required
```

Then I tried ...

```
# wget pecl.php.net/get/gearman-1.1.1.tgz
# tar -zxf gearman-1.1.1.tgz
# cd gearman-1.1.1
# phpize
```

Result ... same error as in attempt 2

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian 6 only has version 0.13 of Gearman. You either need to upgrade that, or find an older version of the PHP extension. You could try installing the packages from [testing](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libgearman-dev).

Comment: @mgorven How is it possible to ugrade the version of libgearman on Debian 6? I'm facing the same problem :(